# cd into volume created by docker

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. Learning it from a book called Learn Fundamentals of Docker 18.x From Packt Publishing. In the chapter on Docker Volume the author creates a vm using docker-machine and then creates a volume called my-data. I have executed the commands as below in first terminal window:

[image: ssh into default docker-machine and create my-data volume and cd into it by elevating myself to sudo]

Then the author creates a container mounting that volume using -v command. I have executed the commands as below in a second terminal window):

[image: Volume Mounted and created a data.txt file]

When I try listing the files in that volume back in my first terminal window I get nothing.

So my understanding was

1. Create volume in docker.
2. Mount the volume in a container.
3. Create some data.
4. Exit the container. And the data will be present.

I also notice that the docker volume inspect my-data provides different mount points:

[image: Mount point in first terminal window]
[image: Mount point in second terminal window]

By this I understand they are different volumes, right?

But I am not seeing any data in the volume. Is my understanding correct? Can anybody explain to me how volumes in docker work?

Also I would like to know how do I navigate to this location from my Mac terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running `docker-machine` which essentially creates a virtual machine on the host with the docker daemon installed. When you run `docker volume create` in there, it creates the volume *within the vm*. I suspect you may be running the docker commands from outside of the docker-machine, but you have created the volume within the docker-machine, which is why they seem to be different volumes.

Ideally you want to configure your host to talk to the docker-machine when executing any docker commands. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#run-containers-and-experiment-with-machine-commands):

```
 $ docker-machine env default
 export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
 export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://172.16.62.130:2376"
 export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/<yourusername>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
 export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
 # Run this command to configure your shell:
 # eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Otherwise, your understanding of docker volumes is correct. Docker volumes are *created and managed by docker* - meaning their physical location can change within the docker host. But data within the volume will always persist until you delete it. According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#more-details-about-mount-types):

> When you create a volume, it is stored within a directory on the Docker host. When you mount the volume into a container, this directory is what is mounted into the container.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I am creating volume inside vm. But executing commands outside.